# Display button only on form input change in angular.js

Tags: angularjs

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><a><i class="icon-white icon-save"></i></a></li>
</ul>

<form>
     <input type="text" value="{{ selectedUser.firstname }}" ng-model="selectedUser.firstname">
     <input type="text" value="{{ selectedUser.lastname }}" ng-model="selectedUser.lastname">
</form>
```

I am dealing with user objects fetched from my REST API. So basically there is a list of users. On click the above form is revealed.

```
function UserController($scope, User){
    $scope.users = User.query();

    $scope.selectedUser = null;

    $scope.select = function(user){
        $scope.selectedUser = user;
    }
}
```

I want to display the save link only when form values have changed. Any ideas how to do this with angular.js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of showing your element only when both fields have data:

```
<div ng-controller="TestCtrl" ng-app>
    <ul ng-show="enableSave(data)">
        <li><a><i class="icon-white icon-save"></i></a></li>
    </ul>

    <form>
        <input type="text" name="firstname" ng-model="data.firstname" />
        <input type="text" name="lastname" ng-model="data.lastname" />
    </form>
</div>
```

And here is your controller:

```
function TestCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.data = {firstname: "", lastname: ""};

    $scope.enableSave = function(data) {
         return data.firstname.length > 1 && data.lastname.length > 1;   
    };    
}
```

You can put any logic you want into `enableSave`.  I've chosen to require that they both have at least two characters... you can do whatever you need.

Here is a jsFiddle that illustrates it: http://jsfiddle.net/nDCXY/1/

**EDIT by OP: my solutions**

```
$scope.enableSave = function(user) {
    if(!angular.equals(user, oldUser)){
        return true
    }else{
        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: Ok thats cool, but imagine there are a lot of fields. And lastname may be empty and firstname changed. The icon will not be displayed...

Comment: I just saw your comment about the multiple fields... try this: http://jsfiddle.net/nDCXY/1/   (I've updated my answer to illustrate how to use a model object to watch)

Comment: Thanks, my question was a bit unclear. I tried to use your solution but it does not work in my case. Look at my edit.

Comment: @artworkadシ You'll have to keep a reference to the old version and the new version of `selectedUser`.  Look at `angular.copy()` to do this.  Then, when the `enableSave` function gets called, compare it to the original value.  Also, you don't need to bind your `value` attributes in your inputs.

Comment: On view init I get "Cannot read property 'firstname' of null" because selectedUser is null until a user is selected.

Answer (score 11):

Give your form a name, such as:

```
<form name="dataForm">
  <input type="text" name="firstname" ng-model="data.firstname" />
  <input type="text" name="lastname" ng-model="data.lastname" />
</form>
```

The form will now be a named model in your scope and you can hide/show the save button based on whether the form is pristine:

```
<ul ng-hide="dataForm.$pristine">
  <li><a><i class="icon-white icon-save"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

This approach has the advantage of showing the save button if you change *any* of the form elements inside the form and the drawback of not checking the input values against their original values, just the fact that they have been edited.

Comment: I think you can easily fix the 'drawback' by improving the ng-hide condition.  Here is one way: `dataForm.$pristine || model.origVal === selectedVal`.